# Checking random Ints?

Tags: java, random, int

We're running a simulator of a board game and we need the computer to choose random position in the array(their board) between 0-5 (all this is done) we implemented an array, player1move, that stores the computer's move choice however if the random value chooses a position that is empty we print "Error, please move again" but the move is added to the movehist array despite being an illegal move. Anyone think of a good way of parsing this random int?

```
int player1move;
     Random rand1 = new Random();
     player1move = rand1.nextInt(6); 
     System.out.println("\nPlayer 1, Your move:");

    int h = 0;
int i = player1move;
player1array.add(i);
System.out.println(player1array);
h = h+1;
```

Comment: Your description is extremely confusing. Is it a possible solution to simply choose *always* a correct position which is not empty ?

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is use Exceptions to control your workflow. You can define a specific Exception for you situation, like `EmptyPositionException`, and use it in that case, like this:

```
int player1move;
Random rand1 = new Random();
player1move = rand1.nextInt(6);
if(isEmptyPosition(player1move){
    throw new EmptyPositionException("Error, please move again");
} 
System.out.println("\nPlayer 1, Your move:");

int h = 0;
int i = player1move;
player1array.add(i);
System.out.println(player1array);
h = h+1;
```

Improvements can be made to the code obviously. This is just to give you an idea of what you can do.

When the code enters the if statement, and the exception is thrown, the rest of the code in the method will not be executed.